# How to make secure boot using Grub2 and UEFI?

Tags: grub2, uefi

I am using micro computer embedded board.I am using ubuntu image for it.
Recently I learn about UEFI for secure boot mechanism.
How can I use UEFI with Grub2 in order to implement secure boot of Linux in my micro computer board?
How to signed binary files for secure boot?

Comment: Beagle is ARM. The concepts of UEFI and secure boot aren't applicable.

Comment: Ya it based on ARM cortex 8

Comment: I changed my question for embedded board  how can I implement it?

Comment: Secure Boot is a UEFI feature. There's no "Secure Boot of Linux". What you're asking now generically is easily searchable: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot and https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/08/11/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot among many other resources. If you have a specific question please post it.

Comment: I read that documentation but I not getting it. Because it says it already given with Microsoft signature and canonical certificate. But here I have to sign my own generated signature and certificate with binary file.So how can I remove default one and add my custom created signature and certificate?

Comment: Microsoft is the provider. The second links details how to sign using Mokutil. What else? Well, there are lots of questions & answers here that you should have searched as well before asking: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=sign+modules