# where to find UEFI firrmware binary?

Tags: uefi

I am running Ubuntu 18. I am working with uefi secure boot. **Where can I find uefi firmware binary file for ubuntu?**
[I tried to find it on uefi.org link](https://www.uefi.org/) but coun't find it out on this link.

Comment: Any Ubuntu 15 is End of Life. Please install a supported release. Firmware, UEFI or BIOS, is provided by the computer's manufacturer.

Comment: Sorry my current version its 18 .Because document says its comes with UEFI support.So now I have a point where I can install uefi firmware on my system .I am currently testing through Vertual box on Windows platform. And later I have to test it on Intel based micro computer board.so I can configure it for secure boot.

Comment: (1) I advise you to [edit] and correct it. Your question may be closed just because of the mention of an EoL release, it's off-topic. (2) Apparently you've learned nothing since your last question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091181/how-to-make-secure-boot-using-grub2-and-uefi) and still don't understand that UEFI is the name of the new firmware standard for X86_64 computers (Intel/AMD). UEFI is used now instead of the old BIOS but like the old BIOS it's brand/model specific and, again, provided by the manufacturer. It can be updated but it's already "installed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question implies that a particular binary would be needed to be used, and that you as the user would be aware of that binary.  Typically, this would not be controlled by you.  If you are interested in development for UEFI and Linux, I suggest you look at participating in the the grub community: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-development.html

First, some background:

An overview of UEFI: https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI

And Ubuntu as it pertains to UEFI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

The second link describes how to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode.  The vast majority of people should read this second link, and follow standard practices for Ubuntu installation with UEFI.

Comment: Yes I read this documents too

Comment: I installed all necessary tools such as shim ,grub2 ,efitootmngr. I have to then use it in a embedded system for secure booting.I created signature and certificate .I also leaned how to bind signature and certificate to binary files with sign tool . Just only UEFI configuration part is missing.

Comment: There's not really enough information here for me to give better advice.  Specifically, what kind of embedded computer (is it still intel, or are you cross-compiling for ARM or some other processor?).  Can the embedded computer accept and boot from a USB drive?

Comment: UEFI configuration is hardware specific. All UEFI settings should be mentioned in the user's manual. And this is completely independent of the OS. Just like the old BIOS.

Comment: Yes its intel one.

Comment: I also found third party UEFI implementation called TianoCore https://www.tianocore.org/